# Integrate PCA factors in a regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, pca

I am a beginner maybe that will seem obvious,

I have a regression looking as : yt =α+βxt+σεt

From another data set I have calculated the PCA factors. Now I am asked to create a regression such as : yt = α + βxt + βjFt,j + σεt

My question is: how can I integrate my PCA factors into my new regression ? In other words, am I supposed to know beta in order to multiply it to my factors ?

Thanks for your answers!

Florian

Comment: Should the σεt term be simply σε without the t?

Comment: @Ron That term probably represents $\sigma\varepsilon_t,$ where presumably $(\varepsilon_t)$ is a *collection* of independent, mean-zero, unit-variance errors. There must be a different one for each observation (for otherwise they are decidedly not independent!), whence the subscript $t$ is necessary.